# Not able to Inserting Correct Mobile number to phpMyAdmin using PHP

Tags: php

If the mobile number 1234567890, the below code is working fine.

If the mobile number is either 2134567890 or another other number not starting with 1, the below code is inserting this number "2147483647" and code is not giving correct output.

Using POST method of FORM i'm getting the values and ACTION is $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']

Using isset($_POST['submit']), written below the code.

Here is the Code:

```
$sql=mysql_query("insert into registration (regname,regmobile) values ('$_POST[regname]','$_POST[regmobile]')");
$sql1=mysql_query("select * from registration where regmobile='$_POST[regmobile]'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql1)>0)
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
    {
        $regname=$row['regname'];
        $regmobile=$row['regmobile'];
        $regid=$row['regid'];
        $reguserid=substr($regname,1,2).substr($regmobile,-4).substr($regid,-2);
        $sql2=mysql_query("update registration set reguserid='$reguserid' where regmobile='$regmobile'");

    }
}
```

Thanks & Regards

Swetha

Comment: For numbers don't use `integer` types. Use `varchar(x)` where `x` is the maximum length of the number.

Comment: May be you can change your mobile number data type from int to varchar.

Comment: [2147483647](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#2147483647_in_computing) and [Integer types (exact values)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types) at the MySQL manual should help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a different data type:

```
bigint
-2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

int
-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)

smallint
-2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767)

tinyint
0 to 255
```

Alternatively as mentioned by blue112, try using VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've reach the limit of Mysql Int.

Consider using a Varchar(10), it will work better.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have reached the limit of `int`

you should use `BIGINT`.

Something like this
[image: BIGINT]